# Jquery: how to validate the value is already exist in dynamic textboxs

Tags: php, jquery, css, dynamic, autocomplete

I am using jquery to create a dynamic text boxes and and also implement the auto complete for each text box added but i dnt know how to compare first text box and second text box in distinct value. for example

```
<input type='text' id='first' value='master' />
<input type='text' id='first1' value='master' />
```

please check this link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6yMNt/6/) and guide me right path to achieve this.
thanks in advance

Comment: link not working [jsfiddle]

Comment: this is my first link add so mistaken.... now updated please check it

Comment: make one array of size 5 then add selected value to that array, while adding next value check if that value is already present in array

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic created texbox use `.on()` for Jquery > 1.7

use `$.each()` and store values of textbox in array

```
var myArrays = [];
  $.each($('[class^=emp_list]'), function (i, item) {
        var grade = $(this).val();  
    myArrays.push( grade );

  });



for(var i=0; i<myArrays.length; i++) {

for(var j=0; j<myArrays.length; j++) {

    if(myArrays[i] === myArrays[j]) 
    {
    alert("Value already exists");return false
    }
  }
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yMNt/25/)

Comment: use .on() for jquery > 1.7 instead of .live()

Comment: Did you check my demo page.....textbox is created done my question is how to validate the dynamic textbox and eachother for example: if i add four textbox and i choose the name S Saravana in all textbox how can i validate the name already selected

Comment: thanks your effect but its not working... whats wrong in my code will u plz upload ur jsfiddle demo

Comment: Plz check the jsfiddle demo

Comment: do you have same problem in that fiddle too ?

Comment: No yeah... just i want to share this to you... thanks

Comment: ok.So finally you got the desired answer.If you got answers from this page please accept the right answer or post new answer and accept it, which might help other having same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, here is a code to answer your question:

```
<input type='text' id='first' value='master' />
<input type='text' id='first1' value='master' />

<input type="button" onclick="compare()" value="compare">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function compare() {
    console.log("reading values <" + $('#first').val() + "> and <" + $('#first1').val() + ">");

    if ( $('#first').val() == $('#first1').val() ) {
        console.log("They are equal.");
    } else {
        console.log("They are not equal.");
    }
}
</script>
```